# dont understand why Inconsistent accessibility error- both public

Tags: c#, facade

```
public partial class FeaturesLogicFacade
{
    private WorldPassportLogic m_WorldPassportLogic;
    private LikedByApp m_LikedByApp;

    private FeaturesLogicFacade()
    {
        m_WorldPassportLogic = new WorldPassportLogic();
        m_LikedByApp = new LikedByApp();
    }

    static readonly FeaturesLogicFacade MyFituresLogicFacade = new FeaturesLogicFacade();

    public static FeaturesLogicFacade FituresLogicFacade
    {
        get { return MyFituresLogicFacade; }
    }

public Dictionary<string, FriendsWithLike> LikedByOperation(FeaturesLogicEnum.eLikedByAppTypes i_eLikedByAppTypes, User i_LoggedInUser) 

public void SubSystemOperation(FeaturesLogicEnum.eFeatures i_FeatureType)

class FeaturesLogicEnum
{
    public enum eFeatures
    {
        NewsFeed,
        Events,
        Massages,
        Checkins,
        Photos,           
        Friends
    };

    public enum eLikedByAppTypes
    {
        SetPicturesLikedByDictionary,
        SetPostsLikedByDictionary,
        SetStatusesLikedByDictionary
    };
    }
}
```

> Error 2   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   'FaceBookApplication.FeaturesLogicEnum.eFeatures' is less accessible
>   than method
>   'FaceBookApplication.FeaturesLogicFacade.SubSystemOperation(FaceBookApplication.FeaturesLogicEnum.eFeatures)' C:\Users\aviram\Desktop\ex02\C13
>   Ex01 MinhDangPhamNguyet 326840139 AviramShiri
>   301374344\Infrastructure\FeaturesLogicFacade.cs   55  21  FaceBookApplication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared `FeaturesLogicEnum` like this:

```
class FeaturesLogicEnum
```

Which has no specific access modifier at this point. And the default access modifier is `internal`, not `public`. Declaring the class as `public` like this should solve your problem.

```
public class FeaturesLogicEnum
```